# no se agrega el valor al array en php

Tags: php, html, array

Estoy creando una pagina web de un juego el cual se van ingresando los nombres de los jugadores y haciendo click en el boton de + se agregan, intento hacerlo con un array en php y luego muestre el echo en html con ajax, el problema es que al agregar el nombre solo se muestra ese y al ingresar uno nuevo se remplaza por el ultimo ingresado.

Este es el código PHP

```
<?php 
$arrayjugadores = ["jugador 1", "jugador 2"];
$nuevojugador = $_POST['nuevojugador'];
$arrayjugadores[] = $nuevojugador;
$arrayjugadoresnew = $arrayjugadores;
$cantidadjugadores = count($arrayjugadores);
$i = 0;
while($i<$cantidadjugadores){
    echo $arrayjugadores[$i] . "\n";
    $arrayjugadores = $arrayjugadores;
    $i++;
}
$_SESSION['array'] = $arrayjugadoresnew;
?>
```

Este es el ajax

```
function agregarjugador() {
  var parametros = {
    "nuevojugador": document.getElementById("jugador").value,
  };

  $.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url: 'includes/agregar.php',
    type: 'POST',

    success: function(mensaje) {
      $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(mensaje);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diría que tendrías que probar algo así:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['array'])) {
    $arrayjugadores = $_SESSION['array'];
} else {
    $arrayjugadores = [];
}
$arrayjugadores[] = $_POST['nuevojugador'];
$salida = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayjugadores); $i++) {
    $salida .= $arrayjugadores[$i] . "\n";
}
$_SESSION['array'] = $arrayjugadores;
echo $salida;
?>
```

### Explicación de los cambios

- El cambio principal que lo arreglaba todo era seguramente que no se iniciaba la sesión, es decir, faltaba esto:

```
session_start();
```

al principio del script.

- Además, tampoco se recuperaban los valores almacenados en la sesión, sino que siempre se iniciaba el array con dos valores incorrectamente:

```
$arrayjugadores = ["jugador 1", "jugador 2"];
```

cuando, ya que al final del script lo intentabas guardar en una sesión, lo deberías haber recuperado de la misma, tal como he puesto en esta respuesta, así:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['array'])) {
    $arrayjugadores = $_SESSION['array'];
} else {
    $arrayjugadores = [];
}
```

donde, si dicha variable de sesión ya contenia datos, la asignamos a la variable `$arrayjugadores`, y si no los tiene entonces la inicializamos vacia para que le podamos agregar el nuevo jugador sin errores después, tal como hacemos aquí:

```
$arrayjugadores[] = $_POST['nuevojugador'];
```

- Luego ya podemos recorrer la variable y devolver sus valores, pero al tratarse de una respuesta de un ajax, no me convence demasiado ir escupiendo `echo` en cada ciclo, por si acaso, asi que mejor vamos agrupando la salida en una nueva variable para ello, que he inicializado antes del bucle:

```
$salida = ''
```

y a la cual vamos agregando los valores dentro del bucle (he usado un bucle del tipo `for` para ahorrarme el contador antes del mismo):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayjugadores); $i++) {
    $salida .= $arrayjugadores[$i] . "\n";
}
```

- Una vez montada la salida, y antes de escupirla de una sola vez, reasignamos el valor de la variable de sesión `array` con la variable `$arrayjugadores` que ya contiene los datos anteriores más el nuevo jugador, dejándola lista para la próxima vez que se agrege un nuevo jugador y vuelva a empezar el script (esto lo podia haber hecho antes del bucle, da igual, pero lo que no queria era hacerlo después de la salida final).
- Y finalmente ya podemos devolver la salida de una sola vez con:

```
echo $salida;
```

Si te fijas he usado el mínimo de variables posibles, a diferencia de tu código original, porque si bien tu código quizás era más claro en cuanto a nombres, tampoco hacía falta usar tantas variables que podían llegar a confundirlo (cuando se pretendia justo lo contrario).

En tu código tenias también una línea que realmente no hacia nada, que era esta:

```
$arrayjugadores = $arrayjugadores;
```

que es como decir que `1=1`, pero no molestaba, aunque era totalmente innecesaria.

Comment: si funciono perfecto, me podrias explicar como la base o el por que no me funcionaba, muchas gracias

Comment: Ale, ya he puesto la explicación ampliada, me alegro que te haya servido. Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta para que la comunidad lo sepa y para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo cuando la respuesta te sirvió.

Comment: gracias bro de corazon, habra alguna forma que te pueda contactar para no estar creando post nuevos por cada duda que tenga? solo por si tengo alguna consulta mas adelanta jajaj, ya e hecho varios proyectos en fullstack pero esta vez no pude resolverlo

Comment: Lo siento, es la mecánica del sitio realizar preguntas nuevas cada vez que se tengan dudas. No se permite el contacto directo entre usuarios, aunque si quieres llamar la atención de algun usuario puedes escribir un comentario poniendo una @ delante de su nick, por ejemplo @TalibanFK, y así le aparece en su lista de mensajes, pero insisto, si hay nuevas dudas que no tengan que ver con esta pregunta o respuesta mejor que hagas una nueva pregunta, pues no siempre encontrarás a los mismos que te atiendan, pues esto no es un trabajo, se hace por voluntad :-)  Saludos!